# Numbering in algorithmicx

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithmicx

1. I have simple code:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \usepackage{algorithm} 
   \usepackage{algpseudocode}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{algorithm}
     \caption{Examples}\label{alg:Examples}
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$

     \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}        

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   How to put a point after the number of the algorithm?
2. I use chapters in `report`:

   ```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

   \usepackage{algorithm} 
   \usepackage{algpseudocode}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{Chapter 1}

   \begin{equation}
   X_2=4
   \end{equation}

   \begin{algorithm}
     \caption{Examples}\label{alg:Examples}
     \begin{algorithmic}[1]
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$
     \State $X=45$

     \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}

   \end{document}
   ```

   [image]

   How to change the numbering to take into account the chapters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the end goal here is to have a `<chapter>.<algorithm>.` numbering within the algorithm caption, yet have `<chapter>.<algorithm>` numbering for the reference. The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) can help here with setting `labelsep` to `period`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx}
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[ruled]{labelsep=period}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}% algorithm counter resets every chapter
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}% Algorithm # is <chapter>.<algorithm>
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Examples}\label{alg:Examples}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State $X=45$
  \State $X=45$
  \State $X=45$
  \State $X=45$
  \State $X=45$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
See Algorithm~\ref{alg:Examples}.
\end{document}
```

The reason for not just redefining `\thealgorithm` to including the trailing period is that it would otherwise then be included when referencing an algorithm, which may cause problems. Algorithm number resetting is scheduled with every chapter.

Comment: when I do the second chapter, the algorithm has the number 2.2, not 2.1. Сan I reset the \arabic{algorithm} in each chapter?

Comment: @user1680906: I've added something to that effect. The [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which defines the `algorithm` environment) uses `\newfloat` (from the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)) to create the float. As such, [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) has doesn't have all the traditional handles, yet `\@addtoreset` works.

Comment: And what do I need to write?

Comment: @user1680906: See the addition in my code: `\makeatletter\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter}\makeatother`